# What would be the possible effect on a country's economy if private banks are declared as non-profit?

Tags: banking

Suppose, there are 100 banks in a country. 50 of them are government owned.

What would be the possible effect on a country's economy if private banks are declared as non-profit? I.e. they can not show any profit. If they have any profit, they must return that profit either to the government's treasury or spend in government's humanitarian projects.

How would that affect or effect a country's economy?

Comment: Would anyone want to open or operate a bank if they are not allowed to make a profit?

Comment: @Andras, no one. This is to discourage the private banks to run a money empire while making the populace poorer day by day.